# Android: .png to Imageview? Most efficent way?

Tags: android

I've got a .png file in my Drawable folder. How do I make it into an Imageview?

Comment: This may be a very basic question, but it's a valid question.

Comment: That's right - it's valid question, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/my_image"
/>
```